# How to set default option for dynamic drop down buttons in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML and jQuery code. When I click Add more button, I need to add a drop down button to the page and **it should be selected with the option which contains it's position value**.

Ex: If there is only one Drop down, it's selected option is 1.
After clicking Add more button, the newly created drop down should be selected option 2. Next drop down should be selected option 3 etc.

But in my code, **when I'm creating more buttons, only the last button will have its position value and all the other drop downs will be reset to "1"**. How can I solve this?

```js
$(".add_more").on("click", function() {

    var order = $(".item_order:last").find("option:last").text();
    var nextItem = parseInt(order) + 1;

    $(".main").last().after($(".main").clone().html());
    
    $(".item_order").append("<option>" + nextItem + "</option>");
    
    $(".item_order:last option:contains(" + nextItem + ")").prop("selected",true);

});
```

```css
.main {
  float : left;
}

.item_order {
  width : 45px;
  margin-right : 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <select class="item_order">
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button class="add_more">+Add More</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the cloning, try this you are getting html contents not select statement, also you are appending the newselect options after the main not inside main, so everytime you select it selects in all the elements.

```
$(".main").append($(".main .item_order:last").clone());
```

```js
$(".add_more").on("click", function() {   
    var order = $(".item_order:last").find("option:last").text();
    var nextItem = parseInt(order) + 1;

    $(".main").append($(".main .item_order:last").clone());
    
    $(".item_order").append("<option>" + nextItem + "</option>");
    
    $(".item_order:last option:contains(" + nextItem + ")").prop("selected",true);

});
```

```css
.main {
  float : left;
}

.item_order {
  width : 45px;
  margin-right : 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <select class="item_order">
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button class="add_more">+Add More</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat simpler way you can do this... unless I misunderstand what you are asking for.

```
$(".add_more").on("click", function() {
    let nextItem = $('.main').children().length + 1;

    let newDropdown = $('<select>').addClass('item_order');

    newDropdown.append($(`<option>${nextItem}</option>`));

    $('.main').append(newDropdown)

    $(".item_order:last option:contains(" + nextItem + ")").prop("selected",true);
});
```